# has anyone has success with vuetify and Laravel 7?

Tags: vuetify.js, laravel-7

I am been trying to install vuetify in more than one project that I am building with laravel 7. I managed to make it work once, but every successive attempt just breaks vuejs itself. I have been following the webpack instructions in the quickstart guide to no avail.

I haven't been able to find any blog posts etc that deal with laravel 7 and it seems that something in the update from 6 has changed how it interacts with vuetify.

If anyone has good installation steps for getting vuetify into a clean laravel 7 application I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: it's a bit tricky to setup, would you like to download a package or setup from scratch?

Comment: Either way. I prefer using CLI, and I'm working with NPM specifically. I made it work quite inexplicably with one project, thankfully the one I most needed for fast development, but I'd like to be able to repeat the parlour trick. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: consider accept my answer? if it helps you?

Answer (score 0):

I Only added the dependencies, added styles and it works